# Change caching location Concrete 5.7

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, concrete5

i have a simple task: store all files(images. videos, cache) in aws s3 (amazon web services).
I changed my storage location with https://github.com/torsoe/concrete5_amazon_s3_filemanager... . Now i need to link my cache to this bucket too, but i dont know where i have to change the settings for the caching system. Later i wannt to use Amazon CloudFront(CDN).
Is there a better way except than changing multiple core files?

greetings
BiggiB

Answer (score 1):

Right now there isn't an easy way to do this, I am actively working to make something like this more easily possible.

You can follow along at https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/issues/4977 if you want to see the progress.

Mike